# Mixed content issue of chrome facing on WebSphere portal content

Tags: websphere-portal, mixed-content

We are working with websphere portal and curently dealing with chrome mixed content issue,

Mixed Content: The site at 'https://tgcs551.commerce.toshiba.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at 'http://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com/cs/groups/internet/documents/document/bl82/mtqw/~edisp/tcxtu_win_614014x.zip?_ga=2.95374741.800005762.1609132621-1301842396.1608820702' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.

we tried below meta data in our static theme also.

1. 
2. 

but we had not get any success.

Then we tried to right Content-Security-Policy in our httpd.conf file of http server of our websphere portal.

1. Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
2. Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src https://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none'"

3. Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self' http://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com; style-src 'self'"

But not get any success, and finally we realised by checking logs the request of http://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com is not going to the http server.

we already have SSL certified website also.
We can't move to https .

so anyone can help us in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Mixed Content: The site at 'https://tgcs551.commerce.toshiba.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but...

Just curious how do you loads `https://tgcs551.commerce.toshiba.com` via https: with invalid cert:
[image]

> 

If you are unable to change `http://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com/cs/...` to the `https:` in the HTML code, the `Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"` should help. But I do not see any Content-Security-Policy in the responce header:
[image]

Of course, CSP header should be publushed on the download page(I do not know it Url). but none of `https://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com/cs/`, `http://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com/cs/groups/internet/`, etc do not have CSP header.

> 

Also weird thing: `http://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com/` redirects to `httpS://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com/`, `http://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com/cs/groups/` redirects to `https:` too. But `http://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com/cs/groups/internet/...` already does not have redirect.
Also all the Urls above redirects to login page, but direct download `http://tgcs04.toshibacommerce.com/cs/groups/internet/documents/document/bl82/mtqw/~edisp/tcxtu_win_614014x.zip` is possible without auth. Was is intended so?

> 

Fix the SSL certs (may be it's better to generate wildcard cert `*.toshibacommerce.com`) and make to be published CSP header.